# Swap two elements in a list of lists based on indices in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, arraylist

Is there any way to swap items in a list of lists based on the index of one item? I've found a solution on how to implement swap onto a single list:

```
swap :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap i j list = let elemI = list !! i
                            elemJ = list !! j
                            left = take i list
                            middle = take (j - i - 1) (drop (i + 1) list)
                            right = drop (j + 1) xs
                    in  left ++ [elemJ] ++ middle ++ [elemI] ++ right
```

From here I've tried to implement my own solution using a tuple as input for an index:

```
swapUp :: [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
swapUp [(i,j)] puz = let emptyTile = puz !! [(i,j)]
          tile = puz !! [(i+1,j)]
          beg = take [(i,j)] puz
          middle = take [(i+1,j-1)] (drop [(i,j+1)] puz)
          end = drop [(i+1,j)] puz
          in beg ++ tile ++ middle ++ emptyTile ++ end
```

The basic idea for my function is that it takes in the index of 0 in a list of lists and returns that list of lists with 0 and the number below swapped. I'm not sure if I can technically use the take, drop, and !! syntax since they take in ints but any advice on this would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to first write a function that replaces an element of a list:

```
replace :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace i x lst = take i lst ++ [x] ++ drop (i+1) lst
```

so (remembering that a string is just a list of characters), we have:

```
> replace 2 'q' "abcdefg"
"abqdefg"
```

This makes it easy to write `swap` without having to do a lot of "index math":

```
swap :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap i j lst = replace i (lst !! j) $ replace j (lst !! i) $ lst
```

giving:

```
> swap 2 4 "abcdefg"
"abedcfg"
```

It also makes it easy to write a function that replaces an element in a list of lists:

```
replace2 :: (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
replace2 (i,j) x lst = replace i (replace j x (lst !! i)) lst
```

See how this works?  It grabs the `i`th row of `lst`, namely `lst !! i`, and uses `replace` to replace its `j`th column element with `x`.  Then, it takes that new row and replaces the `i`th row of `lst` with it:

```
> replace2 (1,2) 99 [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
[[10,20,30],[40,50,99],[70,80,90]]
```

Now, we can swap two elements of a list of lists by writing `swap2` using `replace2` much the same was we wrote `swap` using `replace`:

```
swap2 :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
swap2 (i1,i2) (j1,j2) lst
  = replace2 (i1,i2) (lst !! j1 !! j2)
  $ replace2 (j1,j2) (lst !! i1 !! i2)
  $ lst
```

so that:

```
> swap2 (0,0) (1,2) [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
[[60,20,30],[40,50,10],[70,80,90]]
```

and `swapUp` can be defined as:

```
swapUp :: (Int, Int) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
swapUp (i,j) = swap2 (i,j) (i+1,j)
```

so that:

```
> swapUp (1,1) [[1,2,3],[4,0,6],[7,8,9]]
[[1,2,3],[4,8,6],[7,0,9]]
```

Comment: This is honestly very helpful thank you. I'm new to Haskell and was struggling to understand manipulating tuples within lists and this explains it better than anything I've found.